# Build Gradle Could not find method signingConfigs() for arguments [build_al27st8bbmybmo7hiqzirqbvw$_run_closure2@2176e371]

Tags: flutter, google-play, build.gradle

I want to publish the app in the google play store and I get this error.
Most of the things were done by flutter_automation and I use api 28 for the android system.
When I try the command build flutter app bundle this error appears and I don't get any bundle created.
I cant build my flutter app bundle because of this error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/Users/larry/App/CodeAndroid/navigation/android/app/build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method signingConfigs() for arguments [build_al27st8bbmybmo7hiqzirqbvw$_run_closure2@2176e371] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My Build.Gradle file looks like this:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new FileNotFoundException()("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with    flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

signingConfigs {
release {
    keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
    keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
    storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ?     file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
    storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
}

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
compileSdkVersion 29



lintOptions {
    disable 'InvalidPackage'
}

defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID     (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.example.navigation"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfigs signingConfigs.release
    }
}


}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Thanks for any help.